# Populate a datasource during the start of the spring application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, catalina

I want to run some part of the code to populate the database with dummy data every time the server starts. I use Tomcat as my servlet container. My application is created using Spring. Is there a hook where I can run my code to populate the db just after my application is started?

Comment: What java framework are you using?

Comment: There are some listener for that, you could also use spring Smartlifecycle

Comment: If you happen to be using Hibernate, naming your file import.sql and dropping it into your `resources` folder will automatically import the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different alternatives.

The first one is using Spring's `DataSourceInitializer`. You can pass your initialisation query as a parameter and it executes that query. You can execute any command that you like.

Example:

```
<bean id="dbInitializer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSourceRef"/>
    <property name="enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="databasePopulator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
            <property name="continueOnError" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreFailedDrops" value="true"/>
            <property name="sqlScriptEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="scripts">
                <array>
                    <value type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource">init.sql</value>
                </array>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The second alternative is implementing a Spring `ApplicationListener`. Populate each datum from that listener to your database manually. It is a little harder to achieve.

Example:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = ((ContextRefreshedEvent) event).getApplicationContext();
            // now you can do applicationContext.getBean(...)
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This bean must be initialised by Spring. You can either define it in your `applicationContext.xml` or in your configuration class.

By the way, you can always listen for your ServletContext status by using a `ServletContextListener`. But if you are using Spring, there are easier methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), and if you're using Spring Boot all you have to do is add `liquibase-core` to your classpath, via maven or whatever build tool you're using is. Spring Boot uses YAML files by default. Spring Boot will then run Liquibase on every application startup.